# Scroll animation not functioning on scroll up

Tags: jquery, css

I have a header that nav that I am working on and the issue is that scrolling   upwards does not slide up like it slides down, also the links disappear on scroll up at default state.

look at the jsfiddle, scroll down then scroll up i want the header to slide out like it slid in. the defaultlinks are now gone until refresh.

I have updated all my code here https://jsfiddle.net/r9bdrker/24/

ok the problem here is when you scroll down, then scroll back up the nav dont slide up like it slides down and then it removes the default links

**STATUS UPDATE**

OK I FIGURED out the problem, but need to figure out how to correct it, its my jquery code here is the updated version

```
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
                $('.header').addClass('fixed').addClass('active').removeClass('offset');                            
              } else {
                $('.header').removeClass('fixed').removeClass('active');
           }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);



$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop()>0;   
});



(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > -5) {
                $('.header').addClass('active').addClass('offset'); 
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

when you open the page

the div class should be class="header active offset"
when you scroll down the class should be class="header active fixed"
and when you scroll up it should return to the default "header active offset"

but its not
default state is "header active" 
should be "header active offset"

when scrolling it is "header active fixed" 
but its showing "header active fixed offset"
scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is fine, I reworked your jquery a bit.

```
(function($) {

  var header = $('.header');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
      header.addClass('fixed active').off('transitionend');
        header.removeClass('offset').off('transitionend');
    } else if (header.hasClass('active')) {
      header.removeClass('active offset').one('transitionend', function() {
        header.removeClass('fixed');
          header.addClass('active offset');
      });
    }
  }).scroll();

})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);   
    $('.header').addClass('active');
    $('.header').addClass('offset');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a transition style to the css like this `transition: all 2s;` to the `.fixed` selector It ensures that any new rule being applied takes time to get applied. Instead of `all` you can specify the particular property you want to transform. Check http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp for more details

Comment: that does nothing but fade it in not slide

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because in the JS, you are adding and removing both classes `.fixed` and `.active`.

Based on your CSS, you actually want `.fixed` on the element in the HTML, and to add/remove `.active` in the JS only.

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 350) {
  $('.header').addClass('active');
} else {
   $('.header').removeClass('active');
}
```

Then you'll also need your `transition` on the `.fixed` class

```
.header.fixed {
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hrzh9Lsc/

Comment: Did you look at my answer or my Fiddle? You should add the `fixed` class in the html, and only add/remove the `active` class in the JS. I updated your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r9bdrker/16/

Comment: yes i did but when i use it, it removes my nav at start only shows on sroll and does not smooth when scrolling back up